# Simple PowerAutomate Workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

New to PowerAutomate.  All I want to do is have a simple workflow to change status of completed to "Yes" in a SharePoint task list.  I cannot find anything on how to do this.  I will add it to a list button so the user just needs to hit the completed button (I do have examples on how to do this).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Task list does not support Power Automate, it is recommended that you use the normal list.

**Please following steps:**

1.Create the below columns in the list

- Status of Completed: Choice
- Start Flow: Single line of text

[image]

2.Click on **Integrate** >> **Power Automate** >> **Create your flows**

[image]

3.Flow

[image]

4.Save this flow and copy this flow Id

[image]

5.Go back the list and format the "**Start Flow**" column

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide I used to start a custom workflow approval app which should let you execute a workflow. On the formatting for the column where you are going to have a button you can put something along the lines of:

```
{

{
“elmType”: “button”,
“txtContent”: “Update Status“,
“customRowAction”: {
“action”: “executeFlow”,
“actionParams”: “{\”id\”: \”f191e7c8-1a36-4553-9d64-607764fc6f83\”}”
}

}
```

You will need to update the parameters with your power automate ID.

For the full guide you can view it [here](https://wonderlaura.com/2018/07/18/button-in-sharepoint-list-to-trigger-microsoft-flow/)